# Cannot retrieve the ng-grid value from JSON object in AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

this is the JSON object i got from two table joining..

```
[{"a.opp_name" : "fff",
  "b.client_name" : "Burlington Pension",
  "a.opp_value" : "2.0",
  "a.opp_target_date" : "2014-08-08",
  "d.parameter_name" : "WON",
  "a.opp_rm" : "Lisa Hayden",
  "a.opp_probability" : "43",
  "c.parameter_name" : "Fixed Income",
  "a.opp_next_step" : ""}]
```

and this is the Javascript file.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {      
        data : 'Values',
        selectedItems: $scope.mySelections,
        multiSelect: false,
        columnDefs: [
          {field:'opp_key', displayName:'Opportunity Key',visible:false},
          {field:'opp_name', displayName:'Name', cellTemplate: '<div>{{a.opp_name[0]}}</div>'},
          {field:'b.client_name', displayName:'Client' },
          {field:'a.opp_value', displayName:'Target Amount' },
     // ,  cellTemplate:'<div>${{row.entity.opp_probability}}M <div>'    | date : MM-dd-yy
          {field:'a.opp_target_date', displayName:'Target Date'},
          {field: 'd.parameter_name',displayName:'Stage'},
          {field:'a.opp_rm', displayName:'Owner'},
          {field:'a.opp_probability', displayName:'Probability', },
          // cellTemplate:'<div><progress id="progressBar" data-ng-model="row.entity.opp_probability" data-ng-value="row.entity.opp_probability=convert(row.entity.opp_probability)" max="100" style="width: 50px;"></progress>&nbsp; {{row.entity.opp_probability}}%</div>'
          {field:'c.parameter_name', displayName:'Mandate'}, 
          {field:'a.opp_next_step', displayName:'Next Step'}]
};
```

From here we didn't get the values in ng-grid..

Comment: Are you seeing any error on your browser console? Is your JSON object being assigned to `$scope.Values`? Also, there is an additional `opp_key` field in your columnDefs.

Answer (score -1):

For this issue we use the Surrogate names for the same keyname..here parameter name coming two times.so we can use the surrogate name for differentiating the two parameter names.

Like this..

ColumnNames  ="opp_key,opp_name,client_name,opp_value,opp_target_date,parameter_name,opp_rm,opp_probability,parameter_name,opp_next_step,user_first_name";

SurrogateNames
="opp_key,opp_name,client_name,opp_value,opp_target_date,stage,opp_rm,opp_probability,mandate,opp_next_step,user_first_name";